# Passing complex types via WCF using known types

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on a WCF service.

One of the OperationContracts requres a complex type as one of the parameters (System.Exception to be specific).

When the client calls the proxy if I create a new exception, eg.

```
 System.Exception toNewException = new Exception();
```

And send it... it works rather nicely.

But if i try to send an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'.  The service faults with an unknown type. (see error below)

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:Exception. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' with data contract name
>   'HttpUnhandledException:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Web'
>   is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of
>   known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
>   or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

I've researched the known types attribute... but I have not found any examples or documentation so far that has helped.

Anyone know a good source for information on how I may be able to alter my client/server to accept/work with any kind of exception?

To make my question a little bit more detailed... The error states; 'Add any types not known statically to th elist of known types'.  That is what I want to know how to do specifically for a complex .net object like system.exception.

**Update**

I tried making the following changes:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(HttpUnhandledException))]
void LogError(Exception Exception, Boolean LogInternalFlag, int UserId, int ApplicationId, int SeverityId);
```

and I ended up getting another error!

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:Exception. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal' with data contract name
>   'ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
>   is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of
>   known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
>   or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Atleast the error with the exception made sense... I'm not sure what this means at all.

---

I'm also going to throw in that I did try to serialize the exception as xml and passing it as a string... unfortunately thats not as simple as it may sound, and there are to many considerations to take into account for the serialization of the exception and any inner exceptions.

Comment: What you have tried adding to your web.config?

Comment: Why do you want to send exceptions? Did you look at FaultContracts that is normally the way of how to handle exceptions with WCF.

Comment: @JasonDeOliveira It sounds like the OP is trying to pass an Exception as a parameter to this WCF service, and is having issues sending types that inherit from the type specified in the parm list...

Comment: @Nate correct.  I am passing exceptions as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn’t that the type is complex. Your problem is that your contract was declared with a base class (Exception) and you passed in a child class (HttpUnhandledException). You didn't give the contract serializer any type information for *what the child added to the base definition*. You provide that extra information through KnownTypes.

The best documentation I’ve seen on KnowTypes on MSDN is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

What you are missing in your search is that since you only have a OperationContract (with no DataContract) the attribute you really want to use is [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract
{
   [OperationContract]
   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(HttpUnhandledException))]
   void PassException(Exception c);
}
```

You can put the attribute to just the method or the whole interface.

Note there is a version of ServiceKnownType (and KnowTypes) that takes a runtime method if you don’t know all the possible child (Exception) types at compile time.

Comment: I was working towards that and I thought maybe that would be it... but i got another error on the client... I updated my OP with the result.

Comment: This points out why people use Faults and don't pass Exceptions in Contracts. Exceptions have a Data collection that holds "objects". Same problem. "object" is the ultimate base class. You need to know what's actually in there and add it to the known types list. I haven't worked with HttpUnhandledException before. There might be additional collections I don't know. You could try a debug session to see what possible Types are in there or post another question. Whatever you do it’s not going to be something I would consider "robust".

Comment: i dont expect it to be anything "robust" one of the major issues with exceptoins is the fact that they have innerexceptions... which makes them so difficult to serialize.  unfortunately i came into a shop that had no error logging capabilities, and I need to come up with a solution.  I can log them from the individual applications w/o a problem... my hope was to centralize the logging into one service all of our apps could call... unfortunately, i don't think that is going to work out as I would like due to the nature of the object.

Comment: If that is your use case, Jordan has the right idea. Its not that hard to get the meaningful information into a Data Transfer Object for a WCF call. Even storing Exception.ToString() and some basic meta data like time and application name might be a good first pass.

Answer (score 1):

ErnieL has the correct technical answer.  Pragmatically, however,  I would be prone to either 1) break out the parts of the exception and pass only those along or 2) create your own custom ErrorLog type and send that.

This removes the need to handle subclassing of exception objects and gives you a consistent interface to work with.  Likely, you only need a few members from the exception (error message, inner exception error message, and stack trace).

For inner exceptions, just write a method that loops through the message and concatenates them together.  Do they really need to be stored separately?

Comment: 1) yeah... that would be the easy part, and i've done that in the past. 2) i've done number 1 via this approach.  The problem that I'm running into is implementation.  I have 5 or so medium to large size applications that don't really handle errors well... (throw catch throw catch throw.. which ends up with the users getting system errors)  global asax handling is great... but i end up with 3 levels of inner exceptions that all need to be logged independantly...

Comment: the class object that logs the errors to the database already handles that... I would rather pass one object and log the inner exceptions all at once... instead of making multiple calls to the service... (i am accepting at this point that it probably will not be that simple)

Answer (score 1):

You could work around this by serializing your exception as a byte array, then deserializing it server-side.

Client side, you would use:

```
    try { /* Do something that generates an exception here. */ }
    catch(System.Exception exception)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, exception);
            YourWCFMethodHere(ms.ToArray());
        }
     }
```

and then on the server side:

```
    public void YourWCFMethodHere(byte[] exception)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(exception, false))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            Exception ex = (Exception)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            // Do something with the exception here
        }
    }
```

Of course, you'd want to put some error checking in place, just in case the byte[] passed in isn't actually an Exception.